# Is there any way to use Parent's function under some if condition in Lua

Tags: inheritance, lua

I'm trying to overwrite a `foo()` of parent `A` in child `B`. But instead of overwriting it totally, I want to overwrite it only under certain conditions. A Pseudo example will be:

```
function B.foo()
  if #Certain conditions# then
    # Do what I want to overwrite #
  else
    # Do what the parent wants
  end
end
```

I cannot put the parents implementation here again because I don't have an access to the parent's code.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Certainly. You just have to save / recover the value of the parent's `.foo()`. How you do that depends on the class-framework you use.

Comment: Have you tried to call the parent function with something like `getmetatable(B).foo()`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by "`A` is parent top `B`" you mean that you've set `B` metatable index to `A`. Therefore, before you assign anything new to `B.foo`, it resolves to value of `A.foo`. Just save it into local upvalue and use this reference to call whatever `B.foo` was pointing too until you've assigned new implementation.

```
local parent_foo = B.foo -- save current B.foo, presumably pointing to A.foo at the moment
function B.foo()         -- replace it with new B.foo
  if #Certain conditions# then
    # Do what I want to overwrite #
  else
    return parent_foo()
  end
end
```